# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate') error is thrown , whenever i am trying to navigate to next page

Tags: react-native

> i am getting an error, whenever i am pressing button to navigate to
>   next page , it throws me this error:

*undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')*

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry , Text, View, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import SecondScreen from './SecondScreen';
export default class FirstScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions={
        title:'First',
    }
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            name:'Devansh',
            showName: true,
            message:this.props.message
        }
    }
     static defaultProps = {
        message: 'Hi There'
    }

    render() {
        let name =this.state.showName ? this.state.name:'No name';
        return (
           <View>
                <Text>{this.state.message}</Text>
                 <Text>{name}</Text>
                 <Button
                 onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Second',{user: name})}
                    title="go to SecondScreen"/>
           </View>
        );
    }
}
const ModalStack= StackNavigator ({
    Home:{screen:FirstScreen },
    Second:{
        path:'./SecondScreen',
        screen: SecondScreen}
})
AppRegistry.registerComponent('FirstScreen',()=> FirstScreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`AppRegistry.registerComponent('FirstScreen',() => FirstScreen);`

with following:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('FirstScreen',() => ModalStack);
```

If the issue is still there, try accessing the props using a reference of this. You can do it as :

```
let self = this;
```

And then try using `self.props.navigation.navigate()`

Comment: Did u tried replacing the FirstScreen with ModalStack ?

Comment: yes i did both the changes as u suggested , but now the issue is resolved

Comment: so what was the exact issue ? Does it got resolved by replacing ModalStack with FirstScreen ?